# Question about index of summations

Tags: summation

I have a question in regard to changing the index of summation.

For example, I am confused on why for some problems in my ODE class , such as '

$y''-y'=0$ for example, we suppose the summation of the solution starts at index $n=0$, and then $y'$ starts with $n=1$ and $y''$ starts with $n=2$ for example. Which makes sense to me.

But then for other problems, such as $xy''+y=0$ we start $y$ , $y'$ and $y''$ all at index $n=0$?

Can someone please help explain this to me?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can always start $y'$ series from $n=0$ but the first "useful" index will be $1$. More precisely if $y=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$, then $y'=\sum_{n=0}^\infty na_nx^{n-1}$. The term for $n=0$ is $0$

Same for $y''$ the terms for $n=0$ and $n=1$ are zero the general term of $y''$ being $n(n-1)a_nx^{n-2}$

Comment: Thanks, but what is meant by useful?

Comment: Strictly speaking one shouldn't include $0a_0x^{-1}$ in the formula because that is not well defined at $x=0$.

Comment: Strictly speaking you're right @Gregory Grant. We never get there because each time we derive the constant term of a series we get zero

Comment: Useful means non zero because you can add as many zeroes to a series